# How to handle priorities in a Swifty JSON Alamofire request?

Tags: swift, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch, swifty-json, completionhandler

How can I use the dispatchQueue or something like "await" in Javascript to return a value in `self.arrayData` (because the end of my loop is ran before the previous content). I am used to R and Python where the code runs line by line, What is the best behavior to adopt in Swift ?

Here is the function :

```
func fetch2(){

    var i:Int = 0

    repeat {

    AF.request(itemLookUp[i]).validate().responseJSON { response in

    switch response.result {

    case .failure(let error):
    print("\(error) in fetch2")

    case .success(let value):

        let json = JSON(value)

        //Extract the Matiere for ML Extraction
    self.matiereInput = json["ResultSet"]["0"]["Result"]["0"]["SpAdditional"].string ?? "none"

        let energyCheck:Bool = self.matiereInput.contains("エネルギー") //energy-kcal

    if energyCheck==true && self.arrayData[0]==0.0{
        //regular expression
        var patEnergy = #"(エネルギー)(([^\d]+)(\d+)(\.)(\d+)|([^\d]+)(\d+))"# //avoid the repetition of the pattern within the same matiereinput
        let patEnergy2 = self.matches(for: patEnergy, in: self.matiereInput)
        patEnergy = patEnergy2.joined(separator:"")
        let valueEnergy = self.matches(for: self.regex2, in: patEnergy)
        self.arrayData[0] = Double(valueEnergy.joined(separator: "")) ?? 0.0
        }

    }
        }
        i = i+1
        print(self.arrayData[0])
} while i <= (self.returned-1)
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard pattern is `notify` with a `DispatchGroup`, and then use a completion handler to asynchronously notify the caller of the result:

```
func fetchAll(completion: @escaping (Result<[Double], Error>) -> Void) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    var results: [Double] = []
    var errors: [Error] = []

    for item in lookupItems {
        group.enter()                                          // enter before request

        AF.request(item).validate().responseJSON { response in
            defer { group.leave() }                            // leave when this closure is done

            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                errors.append(error)

            case .success(let value):
                let result = ...
                results.append(result)
            }
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        if let error = errors.first {                          // I don’t know what you want to do if there were multiple errors, so for now I’ll just grab the first one
            completion(.failure(error))
        } else {
            completion(.success(results))
        }
    }
}
```

And then you’d use it like so:

```
fetchAll { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    case .success(let values):
        print(values)
    }
}
```

Now, I wasn’t able to reverse engineer what you were trying to do (you appear to be updating `self.arrayData[0]` in every iteration!), so I just returned an array of `Double`. But you can obviously change the type of `results` and the parameter of the `completion` closure to match whatever is relevant in your case.

But don’t get lost in the details of the above example, but rather just focus on a few key observations:

1. Supply completion handler closure to call when all the requests are done.
2. Use `DispatchGroup` to keep track of when all the requests are done.
3. Supply a `notify` closure to your `DispatchGroup` which will be called when all the `group.enter()` calls are offset by their respective `group.leave()` calls.
4. A more subtle observation is that you should refrain from updating properties from within the `responseJSON` block. Within your asynchronous code, you really want to limit your interaction to local variables if at all possible. Pass the result back in the `completion` closure (and the caller can update the model and the UI as it sees fit).